# get the nearest highest value from a list oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, logic

I have a column in the database in the following format: yymmddhh24miss

```
Sample Data:
140203101241
140202101141
140102101240
143001101244
142801101245
142701131347
142601121542
142101131744
...
```

I need to get the nearest high value from the list. Ex: If I pass 142701131333, then it should return 142701131347 from the above list.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT data
FROM
(
   SELECT data
   FROM tbl
   WHERE data > '142701131333'
   ORDER BY data
) a
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> with t (x) as (
  2  select 140203101241 from dual union all
  3  select 140202101141 from dual union all
  4  select 140102101240 from dual union all
  5  select 143001101244 from dual union all
  6  select 142801101245 from dual union all
  7  select 142701131347 from dual union all
  8  select 142601121542 from dual union all
  9  select 142101131744 from dual
 10  )
 11  select min(x) minx from t where x > 142701131333
 12  /

             MINX                                                               
-----------------                                                               
     142701131347
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(sample_data)
FROM tableName
WHERE sample_data > 142701131333
```